# Autocomplete filed to remove if edit anything

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have added a field with autocomplete. Now I want if I add a field with autocomplete and then if I want to edit the selected field then remove the selected field.

Like this site  [demo site](https://www.montway.com/quote)

```
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];


$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags.concat(bTags),
  response: function(e, result) {
    if (!result.content.length) {
      console.log('No matches!');
      jQuery('#messag').html("Not match...").show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#messag').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You want to delete all the characters with only 1 press of backspace?

Comment: How does the computer know you `want to edit the selected field`?

Comment: (Just noticed there probably is a typo in the title: should that read *Autocomplete field*?)

Comment: When I have type `alw` autocomplete show me `always` in the drop-down. Then I select the drop down. If I will add/remove anything with `always` then this field will be remove. Then user can select again with autocomplete. Please check demo site